ISAPI Hikvison en C#
Tengo este código en C# y estoy usando la api ISAPI de Hikvision.
`
var imgByte = utils.Image.GetImage(filepath);

  if (imgByte == null) return false;


  var client = new RestClient(string.Format("http://{0}{1}", ipAddress, "/ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json"));
  client.Authenticator = new utils.DigestAuthenticator(username, password);
  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
  request.Timeout = 4000;
  request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
  request.AddParameter("FaceDataRecord", body);
  request.AddFileBytes("img", imgByte, "img", "image/jpeg");
  //request.AddFile("img", filepath, "Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
  var responseDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response.Content);

  var a = response.Content;`

Tambien en la variable "filepath" obtengo los bytes de un archivo binario, es decir una imagen .jpeg desencriptada
El problema es que intento registrar un rostro y siempre obtengo esta respuesta.
`{
    "statusCode":   6,
    "statusString": "Invalid Content",
    "subStatusCode":    "SubpicAnalysisModelingError",
    "errorCode":    1610612791,
    "errorMsg": "PicFeaturePoints"
}`

¿Saben Por que ?

Que envias como FaceDataRecord ? , estas seguro que debe ser un POST?

si envio un post, en el body envio {"faceLibType": "blackFD","FDID":"1","FPID":"1"} por lo cual es correcto, pero no se por que obtengo el error que menciono
